# How do I obtain medkits?

Tags: rimworld

How can I replenish medkits in Rimworld?
I spend 2-3 of them after each fight, so now I have only 5 left.

Answer (score 7):

Now as of Alpha 8, a new Herbal Medicine item can be created from Healroot (a growable plant).

Herbal medicine has a cap of 70% effectiveness, while standard medkits have a cap of 100%.

Comment: It is worth noting that herbal medicine apparently needs to be refrigerated, or colonists will not use it to assist their wounded colleagues (or perform operations.) I found this out the hard way :( Also, it can't be used as an ingredient for the Hospital Bed.

Comment: The plant has been renamed to Healroot.

Comment: And it doesn't need to be refrigerated.  (But of course it lasts longer if it's refrigerated or frozen.)

Answer (score 5):

You can purchase them from traders who fly over. When you get a notification that a trader is passing by, direct one of your colonists to a comms console and call the trader. From there, it will list what they have for sale and what you can sell to them. You'll need a orbital trade becaon so that the trader has somewhere to drop the goods.

You can read more about Trading on the Rimworld wiki: http://rimworldwiki.com/wiki/Trade

Comment: This is so expensive.

Comment: Yes, but it's the only way to get more of them, as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 2):

In the base (un-modded) game, Medkits are obtained via trade.  You may wish to try the mod [Simple Medicine Craft](https://ludeon.com/forums/index.php?topic=6652.0), that lets you create Medkits from cloth and berries.

Answer (score 1):

As of 1.0: https://rimworldwiki.com/wiki/Medicine

> Medicine can either be purchased from traders, looted from raiders, or
>   crafted at a drug lab using 3 cloth , herbal medicine and neutroamine
>   (skill requirement: medicine 6+ and crafting 3+, the pawn must also be
>   capable of intellectual work).

Comment: Wow, I didn't even remember I asked this 4 years ago. Recently I tried this game again, and it seems like herbal medicine is enough to heal anything if you have a decent medic.